# How to disable a SELECT OPTION in AG-Grid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid

I'm trying to disable a dropdown element in AG-Grid and React.  Like this example from W3Schools:

option value="volvo" disabled>Volvo

This will be a dynamically built dropdown and I can find no mention of the ability to do this using a cellEditor or cellEditorParams.  I can find no evidence that disabling a dropdown option is possible in AG-Grid.

Comment: You can write a custom cellEditor...

Comment: I've looked at examples of cellEditors and it's clear how to alter the data that is inside the OPTION tag.   I can't see how to actually alter the tag/container, however.  I need an example that demonstrates how to alter the containing tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using a custom  cell renderer for that field i.e

```
 {
     field: 'yourField',
     cellRenderer: 'selectboxRenderer',

    // Here **disable** is the prop that will get passed to your selectBoxRenderer
    // You can put your condition when based on which you want to disable
    // You will also have to receive that **prop** in your component
      cellRendererParams: {
          disable: ({ data }) => { 
              // Your condition here
          },
      }
 }
```